# how to invoke a jsp method onclick/on form submit

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a jsp page with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getWithdrawAmmount()
{
var withdraw=document.forms["WithdrawDeposit"]["AmountToWithdraw"].value;
document.getElementById('hidden').type = withdraw;
}
</script>
```

---

```
<form method="POST" name="WithdrawDeposit" onsubmit="getWithdrawAmmount()">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="text" size=5 name="AmountToWithdraw"></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Withdraw"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="">
```

---

```
<% String AmountWithdraw = request.getParameter("hidden");  %>
<%!
public void Withdraw(){     
    int Amount = Integer.parseInt("AmountWithdraw");
Deposit deposit = new Deposit();
deposit.WithdrawMoney(AmountWithdraw);  
} %>
```

---

I need to activate the Withdraw() method on form submit and get the text input.
the javascript hold the value inserted in 'hidden' and i can access it later.
but i can't call to : <% Withdraw(); %> from inside javascript.

how can i call Withdraw() after button click?

10x

Comment: simply adding onClick="Withdraw();" in the input element should be enough.

Comment: @dystroy — It is server side code, so no, that shouldn't work.

Comment: doesn't work. starting to wonder if it's even possible..

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Do you want to call the browser side function of the server side's one ? My comment was for calling the browser side's one.

Comment: server side function..
the problem is that i can't call the method Withdraw() on form submit.

Answer (score 3):

First off your line of code has issues

```
document.getElementById('hidden').type = withdraw;
```

It is looking for an element with an id of hidden. Not a name, an id. So add an id to the element you are referencing.

Second you are setting a type. Don't you want to set the value?

So the HTML would look like

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" id="hidden" value="" />
```

and the JavaScript would be

```
document.getElementById('hidden').value = withdraw;
```

Now if you want to call a function on the server, you either need to post back the form or make an Ajax call.

Comment: 10x, you are correct. since that wasn't related to my issue i didn't pay attention.

Comment: @WordToTheWise "[...] either post back the form or make an Ajax call." You're confusing when and where code is executed: JSP/Java code is executed on the server, before the client ever sees any HTML or JavaScript.